# java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper?

Tags: java

My applet cannot implement following statements:

```
Method p11Getinstance = PKCS11.class.getMethod("getInstance", String.class,
        String.class, CK_C_INITIALIZE_ARGS.class, Boolean.TYPE);
```

and throws an exception:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper)

If I edit `java.policy` in javahome, the above exception will disappear, but I don't want to go this way. I want to edit my code.

When I try to add some statements:

```
AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        try {
            p11Getinstance = PKCS11.class.getMethod("getInstance", String.class, String.class, CK_C_INITIALIZE_ARGS.class, Boolean.TYPE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

And then use my certificate to sign jar file of the applet, will this exception still appear?

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to add the following permission in the `.java.policy` file:

```
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper";
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.sun.security.pkcs11";
```

Comment: -1 because the question clearly already knows this is a possible fix: "If I edit java.policy in javahome, the above exception will disappear, but I don't want to go this way." If you know that this fix is the _only_ possible fix, please speak to that.